# What reason is there to not add nested class/struct resolution in C++ when performing method calls?

Tags: c++, scope

Considering the following toy program:

```
struct Foo
{
  struct Bar {};

  Foo(Bar b);

  Bar m_b;
};

Foo::
Foo(Bar b) // Bar resolved properly
: m_b(b)
{ }

int main() {

    auto f = Foo( Bar() ); // Bar not resolved  

    return 0;
}
```

Why do I need to explicitly type `Foo::Bar` when calling the `Foo`'s constructor? Is there a technical reason for this? Is there any way to resolve `Bar` without typing `Foo f(Foo::Bar b);`?

Any argument can be made that if there is another `Bar` then it could get ambiguous. But we deal with those kind of ambiguities all the time (by manually resolving the symbol to remove ambiguity).

---

From the comments it seems people are wondering why you would ever to do this. Well, languages like Objective-C have messages that have additional message names to help indicate the information that is being passed.

I found this very helpful especially when reading code after it has been written. What I have above is a trivial program. But imagine if there was a class `Ray` which has an origin and direction. If we were to construct it like this `Ray r(Vec3(0, 1, 0), Vec3(1, 0, 0))`, which vector is the origin and which is the direction? The verbosity helps in this case. We can have strong typedefs for `Vec3` named `origin` and `direction`. This will allow us to do something like this `Ray r(origin(Vec3(0, 1, 0)), direction(Vec3(1, 0, 0))`.

But of course, unlike objective-c, I have to resolve the names (be it a nested `struct/class` or `strong_typedef`) like this `Ray r(Ray::origin(Vec3(0, 1, 0)), Ray::direction(Vec3(1, 0, 0)))` which can become even more verbose with namespaces.
**/Edit**

> I guess this question is stemming from frustrating when working with libraries (including my own) where there is liberal use of `strong_typedef` or a nested `struct/class` inside another `class` (e.g. a parameters class) and I am forced to resolve the name fully.
>
> Of course, I would not opt to remove the `strong_typedef` as it definitely makes the code more readable.

Comment: The rules are in  [basic.lookup.unqual], specifically paragraph 8.

Comment: Why would you ever want to do this?  Just put both structs in the same namespace.

Comment: @RobertHarvey This is very common in libraries I have come across. If you put both structs in the same namespace, then `Bar` is now polluting the external namespace. Not only that, if the same namespace has other `Bars`, you have more issues. Imagine `Bar` is called `Params`, which stores a bunch of parameters for class `Foo`. And to be consistent across a library, a number of classes have a `Params` struct nested inside the parent class.

Comment: Why isn't the parent class responsible for instantiating the nested structure?  Why would you need to do that from the outside?

Comment: @KerrekSB That is some of the densest text I have seen in the standard. I have no idea what any of it means. Care to write an answer?

Comment: @Barry: I didn't think the answer would be very useful. It's basically just because that's how the rules are. If the OP is looking for deep philosophical insight I have none to offer. Other than perhaps that the question is the wrong way round and that the true marvel is why unqualified `Bar` *can* be used in the out-of-line member definition.

Comment: @KerrekSB I, for one, was surprised that you could use `Bar` unqualified in that spot...

Comment: @Barry: Right, and that's where 3.4.1/8 comes in. But the OP is asking for the other, less interesting issue: Why can a thing with one name not be called by some other name. :-(

Comment: @RobertHarvey See edit - and to answer your question specifically, the parent _can_ do this, but the point of having `Params` is to allow the user to pass `Params` to the constructor of the parent class. The parent class then uses these `Params` for construction and get the object in a usable state. Again, this is very common (e.g. see Havok physics library) and makes the code more readable, albeit verbose.

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is that it's just how scope works.

`Bar` is nested inside of `Foo`. Therefore `Bar` is available without qualifications to everything else that's (logically) "inside" of `Foo`. That includes the implementations of `Foo`'s member functions, even if the code for the implementation is located outside of `Foo`'s class definition.

Other code that simply *uses* a `Foo` but isn't itself a part of `Foo` doesn't get that "insider information" though. To any code that's logically "outside" of `Foo`, `Bar` doesn't exist on its own--to the rest of the world, the name is `Foo::Bar`, not just `Bar`.

This is a bit like people's names. To my family and close friends my name is just "Jerry". If they're calling me on the phone from some remote location, I'm still just "Jerry". To the rest of the world, however, "Jerry" isn't enough--there are too many "Jerry"s in the world, so they use my full name. Of course, in some cases, even that's not enough--some names are common enough that there are hundreds or even thousands of people with the same name. C++ deals with that by adding namespaces, so we can specify a scope inside of which everything knows each others names, but code outside that scope has to either qualify the names with the name of the namespace, or else specifically make that name visible in the local scope.

Namespaces bring up a separate but somewhat related item, called Argument Dependent Lookup (ADL, aka "Koenig Lookup"). This only works with names in a namespace (not a struct/class). It can/will find the name of a function in a namespace based on the fact that you pass an argument to the function that's of a type that's also declared in that same namespace.

For example, let's turn your `Foo` into a namespace, and along with the `Bar` type, we'll define a `baz` function:

```
namespace Foo {
    struct Bar {};

    void baz(Bar const &b) { std::cout << "Foo::baz()\n"; }
}
```

So, the obvious way to call `baz` would be something like this:

```
Foo::Bar b;
Foo::baz(b);
```

This is simple and obvious--we call `Foo::baz` passing a `Foo::Bar` as an argument, all as we'd immediately expect. For this case, we can omit the `Foo::` qualification, and just call `baz` with its unqualified name:

```
baz(b);
```

This uses ADL. The argument `b` is of type `Foo::Bar`. When the compiler is looking for `baz` it first looks in the local scope for something named `baz`. Since it doesn't find it, it then looks at the argument type, and sees that `b` is of a type that's defined inside of namespace `Foo`. Based on that, it searches again for `baz` inside of `Foo`, and finds it, so that's what gets invoked.

Comment: `ADL` and _shadowing_ is the reason I started thinking about this issue.  In the example, if the language allowed `Bar` to be unqualified, but required `Bar` to be qualified if ambiguity arose (similar to what happens if we use `using namespace a; using namespace b` and `foo` happens to be in both `a` and `b` namespaces) - then we could have much more concrete argument types (instead of 3 `floats`, or 3 `Vec3fs` or `bools`) in methods making the code much clearer. I was wondering why this wasn't possible due to some technical reason. Nevertheless, +1 for a good explanation.

Answer (score 1):

> `Ray r(origin(Vec3(0, 1, 0)), direction(Vec3(1, 0, 0));`

In C++, the [Named Parameter Idiom](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/named-parameter-idiom.html) is one way to get similar type safety and self-documentation, albeit with notation a slightly more verbose notation:

```
Ray r(Ray::Params().origin(Vec3(0, 1, 0)).direction(Vec3(1, 0, 0));
```

At least the `Ray::Params().` bit need not be repeated the way `Ray::` must for each parameter when using `Ray`-scoped types.

This has other benefits too - parameters can be specified in various orders, affect other parameters as they're set etc., but can also force some "house-keeping" and checks to run-time (e.g. on the provision of specific parameters), which can make for slower and more fragile applications.

---

Another approach is to enrich `Vec3` with a member function for creating an ordered pair of `Vec3`s, e.g.:

```
Vec3_FromTo Vec3::operator->(const Vec3& rhs) const
{
     return Vec3_FromTo(*this, rhs);
}
```

Then support construction of `Ray` like this:

```
Ray r(Vec3(0, 1, 0) -> Vec3(1, 0, 0));
```

This can also be provided as a non-member function, allowing say:

```
Ray r(From_To(Vec3(0, 1, 0), Vec3(1, 0, 0)));
```

No particular reason for `From_To` to be defined within `Ray` as the concept is generalised enough to be reusable.

Still, this `Ray` constructor is itself a bit of a special case in that there're two arguments with a logical relationship: it's worse if you want to support say overloads `Circle(Radius);` and `Circle(Circumference);` - both of which trivially wrap `double`s, but then a supporting `enum Measurement { Radius, Circumference };` can allow `Circle(double, Measurement)`.  That's clumsier and less reliable for multiple arguments.

Comment: I like the `Params` solution the most and have used it in libraries I have written. It still requires qualification which can get really bad when dealing with template classes, in which case the user must either `typedef` the class before using it to reduce the mess (adding cruft to code, especially if the type is not directly used e.g. returned by a function and stored using `auto` - I guess `decltype` can be used in those cases) or the library must provide an appropriate `typedef`, which of course is not possible for all template types.

Comment: @Samaursa interesting... I can't see net benefit in just having a `Params` type without using the Named Parameter Idiom, as the motivating issues about parameter ordering are simply shifted from the `Ray` constructor to the `Params` constructor - it only seems useful if you're storing parameter objects for reuse.  `Origin` and `Direction` in your example makes sense as it gives type safety to a subset of the constructor parameters, but `Params` by itself - what's it buying you?